# replaceAll() and replaceFirst(). Which one is faster and efficient?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am replacing a string using RegEx. I knew that the pattern which I search in that string may occur only once. Both `replaceAll()` and `replaceFirst()` methods will work for my scenario. But I am using `replaceAll()` method.

In my application every millisecond on computation is precious.

Is my choice right? Which one is better for my scenario? Any comparisons available? Please guide me.

Comment: I would use a CPU and Memory profiler to tune your application. If you don't do this this you can make changes which a) add complexity but make no difference b) help but have little impact c) make matter worse.

Comment: A quick look at the javadocs for replaceFirst and replaceAll would have cleared a lot, I think http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: I have no idea why one would want to ask this. `replaceFirst` cannot possibly perform worse than `replaceAll` and it surely could perform better. If every ms is important to you, why did you use `replaceAll`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If every millisecond is precious for you then you should *measure* not ask. In any case, my *guess* (again: verify by measuring) is that `replaceFirst()` will be faster since it can stop after the first match instead of searching for others (that won't exist in your case).

You probably also want to precompile the regex as that saves you the time to do so on every call to `replaceFirst()`. Or look for a way of avoiding regular expressions if it's just a simple string replace.

But I stress again: Use a profiler to find out where you spend the most time and optimise that part. It's not very useful to over-optimise a statement that is called exactly once and contributes just 0.07 % to the total runtime while ignoring the fat loop right next to it, eating up 80 % of your runtime. Also so far my experience has been that the bottlenecks are very often in the most surprising places and *not* where you'd naïvely expect them.

Answer (score 1):

Surely `replaceFirst()` is faster, it will stop after the first occurence while `replaceAll()` will scan the entire input.